# Clarification in the Theano tutorial

Tags: python, numpy, theano, gradient-descent, deep-learning

I am reading [this tutorial](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/craffel/theano-tutorial/blob/master/Theano%20Tutorial.ipynb) provided on the [home page of Theano documentation](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/index.html)

I am not sure about the code given under the gradient descent section.

[image]

**I have doubts about the for loop**.

If you initialize the '**param_update**' variable to zero.

```
param_update = theano.shared(param.get_value()*0., broadcastable=param.broadcastable)
```

and then you update its value in the remaining two lines.

```
updates.append((param, param - learning_rate*param_update))
updates.append((param_update, momentum*param_update + (1. - momentum)*T.grad(cost, param)))
```

Why do we need it?

I guess I am getting something wrong here.
Can you guys help me!

Comment: What does 'and you **dun** update its value in remaining two line.' mean?

Comment: Could you please add code and not a screenshot?

Comment: Its under gradient descent section here: http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/craffel/theano-tutorial/blob/master/Theano%20Tutorial.ipynb

I meant that u initialize the param_update in first code line I provided, and you dun update in remaining two code line given above.

I will try to add code from next time!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The initialization of `param_update` using `theano.shared(.)` only tells Theano to reserve a variable that will be used by Theano functions. This initialization code is only called once, and will not be used later on to reset the value of `param_update` to 0.

The actual value of `param_update` will be updated according to the last line

```
updates.append((param_update, momentum*param_update + (1. - momentum)*T.grad(cost, param)))
```

when `train` function that was constructed by having this update dictionary as an argument ([23] in the tutorial):

```
train = theano.function([mlp_input, mlp_target], cost,
                        updates=gradient_updates_momentum(cost, mlp.params, learning_rate, momentum))
```

Each time `train` is called, Theano will compute the gradient of the `cost` w.r.t. `param` and update `param_update` to a new update direction according to momentum rule. Then, `param` will be updated by following the update direction saved in `param_update` with an appropriate `learning_rate`.